# re and binary file, python strange behavior

Tags: python, regex, binaryfiles

i have a strange behavior of re.search on a binary file. Here is my python screenshot :

[image]

As you can see, i have two problems :

- re can't find a pattern which is indeed in the file
- include "\x5b" in an expression results in an error

Any idea?

Comment: Please post your terminal output *as text*, not as a screenshot. No-one can search for text in a screenshot, and we can't copy-and-paste your screenshot to reproduce the error.

Comment: I can't understand why you are using regexes here at all. Surely you're just searching for literal bytes within a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\x5b` is the ASCII `[` character, the left square bracket. That's a *regex meta character* forming the start of a `[...]` character class specification and needs to be escaped if you want to match a literal `[` character:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.search('[', '')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "/Users/mjpieters/Development/venvs/stackoverflow-2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 251, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
>>> re.search('\[', '')
```

The same applies to `\x41`, that's the `^` character, which in a regex context matches the *start* of the string only, not the literal character `^`. Since you tried to match data *before* the `^` point the regex can't 
match anything, simply because that makes the anchor invalid.

If you are only searching for literal text matches, don't use a regex. You could just use [`str.find()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) or [`str.index()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.index) to get the index of matched text.

If you are using this in a larger expression and *generate* the expression from data, then use [`re.escape()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) to ensure all metacharacters are properly escaped first.

Comment: right, i know understand clearly the reason behind my problems. str.find() is indeed much better in my case. Thanks!